# Is there a well-defined algorithm to find preimages in MD5?

Tags: hash, md5, algorithm

I know MD5 is no longer secure, but is there an algorithm running in polynomial time to find preimages of a given hash, or is it just bruteforce?

Comment: Please start with some research of your own, like doing a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=md5+preimage+algorithm) or just reading the [Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Preimage_vulnerability)

Answer (score 4):

**You won't be able to find a preimage for MD5.**

The [best preimage attack](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-01001-9_8.pdf) against MD5 has a complexity of 2<sup>123.4</sup> and requires 2<sup>45</sup> × 11 words of memory. This is faster than brute force, which has a complexity of 2<sup>128</sup>, but still isn't practical. The only attack that can be realistically performed against MD5 is collision and chosen-prefix collision.

Even MD4 isn't particularly vulnerable to preimages, with [its best preimage attack](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-17373-8_4.pdf) requiring 2<sup>99.7</sup> operations and 2<sup>55</sup> memory, finding a preimage of at least 2<sup>50</sup> blocks! Preimage attacks are *hard*.

Comment: The official download link doesn't look paywalled https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-01001-9_8.pdf

Comment: @BrunoRohée Good catch. I've edited the link.